# Looping through mutliple select field option values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select field, and multiple options can be select. The values for these options are image urls (e.g.'img/image.png'). When a user clicks on an option, I want the image (or images if multiple are selected) to appear below the select field. I am confused by what jQuery is outputting. So far I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.logo-select').on('change', function(){

        var options = $('.logo-select').val();

        $(options).each(function(){
            console.log(this);
        });

    });
});
```

I assumed this would output the value of each option, but instead I get the following in my console:

```
String {0: "i", 1: "m", 2: "g", 3: "/", 4: "i", 5: "m", 6: "a", 7: "g", 8: "e", 9: ".", 10: "p", 11: "n", 12: "g", length: 20, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "img/image.png"}
```

Why is it breaking the value down into individual letters? How can I make it output just the image path?

Comment: You can use `$(this).find('option:selected')` in `.on("change", ...)`

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the context of your application referes to the `$(options)`-Object.

Try to bind `this` from the context of your outer function to the inner callback with the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)-function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.logo-select').on('change', function(){
        var options = $('.logo-select').val();

        $(options).each(function(){
            console.log(this);
        }.bind(this));

    });
});
```

Working with `this` can be a bit tricky at times, `this` always refers to the context it is called from. That means, inside the `each`, `this` represents `$(options)` and outside, it represents `$('.logo-select')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` to bind your selection

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.logo-select').on('change', function(){
        var options = [];
        options.push($(this).val());

        $(options).each(function(){
            console.log(this);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the jsfiddle, this might help you https://jsfiddle.net/bov3mLqr/

```
$('.logo-select').on('change', function(){

    var options = $('.logo-select').val();
    var splitOptions = options.split(',');
    console.log(splitOptions);
    for(var i=0; i<splitOptions.length; i++){
        console.log(splitOptions[i]);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).find('option:selected')` in `.on("change", ...)` and You can fill your result array in each loop like following.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logo-select').on('change', function(){            
        
        var options = $(this).find('option:selected');       
        var arr = [];
        
        console.clear();
        $(options).each(function(){
           arr.push($(this).val());
        });
        
        console.log(arr);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="logo-select" multiple>
  <option value="img/img1.png">option1</option>
  <option value="img/img2.png">option2</option>
  <option value="img/img3.png">option3</option>
  <option value="img/img4.png">option4</option>
</select>
```